# Does changing CNAME for amazon cloudfront slows the download in anyway?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon

I'm planning to use Amazon S3 with Cloudfront as CDN network.

But I'm guessing that changing the url from `345345df4.cloudfront.com` to `sub.domain.com` will slow the process of download

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

It will make no difference. Clients have to make a DNS lookup to convert the name to an IP address; using a CNAME might make that slightly slower, but by tens of milliseconds. The download itself uses the IP address, and will be entirely unaltered.

Comment: so do you think the hosting that holding the subdomain, will be affected and maybe it will affect the process also if it was slow and couldn't handle thousands of connections

Comment: no, DNS lookup is already highly optimised and cached and distributed in many locations including the user's computer. using a CNAME won't have any practical affect on whoever is hosting your DNS records